# Trying to click a see more tab using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Ive been using selenium to scrape a site to retrieve some information.
the information is hidden behind a see more tab that is being revealed using javascript when i click it. I have tried many different methods to get the the information visible. and it does not seem to be working .

I have tried to use action chains along with the regular xpath methods to chain the functionality together but it still does not seem to be clicking all the other info is pulled and the button text is printed out to the console instead of being clicked.

```
    def grabDetails(self):
       facts = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//section[@id='hdp-content']/main/div/div[4]")
       for fact in facts:
           details = fact.text
           print(details)
    def moreFeatures(self):
        view_more_elements = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'See More Facts and Features')]")))
        # features.click()
        ActionChains(view_more_elements).double_click().preform()
        # self.browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', features)
```

Im trying to get the information from this page printed out !
[here is the zillow page that im trying to **scrape**](https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/11612-Newburgh-St-Jamaica-NY-11412/32143551_zpid/?fullpage=true)

its the see more sections part below it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `view_more_elements` as a `WebDriverWait` object rather than a `WebElement`. This will prevent the object from being clickable. You just need to run `WebDriverWait` as it's own call, then `.click()` the element.

```
view_more_xpath = '//div[@class="read-more zsg-centered"]/a'
view_more_elements = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, view_more_xpath))
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(view_more_xpath).click()
```

EDIT: you don't actually need to set `WebDriverWait` to `view_more_elements`. You can just do:

```
view_more_xpath = '//div[@class="read-more zsg-centered"]/a'
WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, view_more_xpath))
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(view_more_xpath).click()
```

Comment: i love you your the best in the whole wide world thank you so much